# PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined function dl() in /var/www/html/cake/bootstrap.php on line 29

Tags: php, apache, cakephp

After an upgrade of the PHP version, I am starting to see this error on any request to serve up a PHP file

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function dl() in /var/www/html/cake/bootstrap.php on line 29

These are the PHP Version details 
Name       : php
Arch       : x86_64
Version    : 5.3.22
Release    : 15.el5.art
Size       : 7.5 M
Repo       : installed
Summary    : The PHP HTML-embedded scripting language. (PHP: Hypertext Preprocessor)
URL        : http://www.php.net/
License    : PHP
```

This is the output from the uname -a command

```
Linux ip-72-167-55-181.ip.secureserver.net 2.6.18-308.1.1.el5.centos.plus #1 SMP Wed Mar 7
```

Apache version Info

```
Server version: Apache/2.2.3
Server built:   Feb 23 2012 21:16:56
```

Cake PHP Version

```
'1.3.13'
```

Googling this does not seem to provide me with any relevant results. Hoping the someone can provide me with some insight on the issue.

Comment: and what is in /var/www/html/cake/bootstrap.php on line 29?

Comment: Did you read documentation: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.dl.php?

Answer (score 4):

As per the docs: http://php.net/dl

`dl()` has been removed from some SAPIs (server apis, e.g. apache, iis, etc...) as of PHP 5.3.0

Comment: Well this works on PHP 5.3.6, so not sure why it stopped working on 5.3.22. What are my options? Should I upgrade the version of Cake to higher version?

Comment: unless newer cakes remove the requirement for dl(), probably wouldn't matter much.

Comment: Agreed. Maybe I need to pose this question to the Cake forums. They should be removing this call because it is no longer supported by SAPI's.